# Accessing properties of parent template in child template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a polymer element which has a nested template. I want to access properties of parent template in the child template.

```
<dom-module id="gallery-content">
<template>
    <template is="dom-bind">
        <iron-ajax url="/getData" last-response={{data}} auto></iron-ajax>
        <table id="table-stencils">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>{{contentType}}</p>
                    <hr>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <image-block description={{data.description}}
                                 lastmodified={{data.lastModified}}
                                 imagepath="../../images/11.jpg"></image-block>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <image-block description={{data.description}}
                                 lastmodified={{data.lastModified}}
                                 imagepath="../../images/12.jpg"></image-block>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <image-block description={{data.description}}
                                 lastmodified={{data.lastModified}}
                                 imagepath="../../images/13.jpg"></image-block>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <image-block description={{data.description}}
                                 lastmodified={{data.lastModified}}
                                 imagepath="../../images/14.jpg"></image-block>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </template>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "gallery-content",
        properties:{
            contentType: {
                type:String,
                value:"Others"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am not able to access `contentType` property of the parent element.
I am using another polyment() inside this gallery-content element.

Comment: Why do you have dom-bind inside template. dom-bind is use to create polymer object in normal html without creating a new element

Comment: @a1626: I have another polymer element inside child template and I am doing <iron-ajax> calls needed for data binding.

Comment: I am a little confused how can you create a new polymer element inside another. And why would you use that? what are you fetching using ajax call? Anyways dom-bind usage says that use it to create an element from html without creating custom element.

Comment: @a1626: I have updated the code to give you an understanding of what i am trying to do.

Comment: i still don't see the need for `dom-bind` if you remove it your code will run fine

Comment: I tried doing that, {{data.anything}} doesn't work and <image-block> doesn't load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115415/discussion-between-afaq-and-a1626).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a running [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEGlunXg1Wa2pj8gHfAQ?p=preview) of your element without `dom-bind`. Please note i've used a json as `getData` service and a temporary element for `image-block`